# How to display Spring Form Validation message inside Jquery Dialog?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, server-side-validation, spring-validator

I have a Jquery Dialog which contains text fields wherein user can edit his personal details. An Ajax call is made to backend controller when user clicks Update button. Now I need to perform Server Side Validation (Spring Validation).

How to display spring validation messages inside Jquery Dialog ? I am struck with this problem.

Can anyone help me !!!

Comment: What is returned in the ajax-response when server-validation fails ? You can simply collect all errors in the server-side & send as JSON in the ajax-response & write some jquery code to display that.

Comment: Always use firebug with ajax calls.Below is the link which describes this.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/